# NuGet - Parse SDK style projects for all NuGet references

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to parse the new SDK style projects for all NuGet references and version using `NuGet.Client` or otherwise.

I imagine you can't just parse the `csproj` files themselves as `PackageReference` can come from `build.props` or even custom `msbuild` targets.

The use case is that I would like to write a xplat .net core global tool that would analyze a solution with multiple projects and list out all the directly referenced nuget packages and show if there is a newer version available.

Comment: All this information is in the generated obj/project.assets.json file so you could read if you cannot find anything in the NuGet API.

Comment: You are talking about `project.json` based projects or what? Can you share a sample project you are talking about? The project.json has all `nuget` dependencies directly so not sure what the question exactly is

Comment: No, `project.json` is depricated. I'm talking about the new `csproj` format - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Comment: What do you mean by all NuGet references?
Direct references? All resolved references?

Only the direct references will be specified in the project. 
An easy way to get those would be to call the "CollectPackageReferences" target which is what the commandline NuGet implementations do. 

If not as Matt said, you can read the assets file, and some of the APIs there. 
Specifically https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.ProjectModel/LockFile/LockFile.cs contains everything.

Comment: I have updated the description with my use case. To be honest, it feels like the whole msbuild / nuget linkage makes it impossible to complete the task externally in a cross platform way